# ASP.NET Tabs to Navigate to Existing Pages

Tags: asp.net, tabs, multiview

I am writting a log viewer application,and i have all the pages already written. (Visualizer,Configuration and a third one).

Is it possible to create a tabbed control or anything like this,that allow me to navigate through those pages without having to paste all the code of all the pages in a single .aspx file ?

How can i make a tabbed control (multiview,i guess,right ?) to navigate to the existing pages?
Once i click a tab,it changes the content of a container above the tabs.

Is it hard to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question corrctly, You are probably looking for something like a jquery tabs menu. 
[option 1](http://yensdesign.com/2008/12/create-a-smooth-tabbed-menu-in-jquery/) - try the demo and see if it is what you are after
[Option 2](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/tabs.html) - this is the demo

Comment: Both are almost the same thing,and yes,this is what i want,but the content of each tab will be much bigger. Like a whole page of logs in one tab,while,in the second one,a form only.
How do i do that ? Is there any code sample avaible ?

Comment: Nevermind,i realized that i having all the code from all the pages in a single page is not good.
I will use buttons side-by-side and change pages on the "click" method.

Thanks again,and ossyr for this waste of your time.